# Are there any way to send value into protected override void OnActionExecuted in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to send radio button value to controller `protected override void OnActionExecuted` which is inside `_Layout`.

Can anyone please suggest me how can I do this?

_Layout

```
<div class="NorthSouthHemisphere">
      @Html.RadioButton("NorthernSouthernHemisphere", "NH")Northern
      @Html.RadioButton("NorthernSouthernHemisphere", "SH")Southern
  </div>
```

Controller

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            if (User != null)
            {
                var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
                var username = User.Identity.Name;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
                {
                    var user = context.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);
                   var Account = context.Account.SingleOrDefault(u => u.AccountId == user.AccountID);
                    var Country = context.Country.SingleOrDefault(u => u.CountryId == user.CountryID);
                    string fullName = string.Concat(new string[] { user.FirstName, " ", user.LastName });

                }
            }
            Hemishpere();
            base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        }
```

Script

```
 $(document).on('change', '.NorthSouthHemisphere input[type = "radio"]', function () {
                 var selectedVal = "";
                var selected = $(".NorthSouthHemisphere input[type='radio']:checked");
                if (selected.length > 0) {
                    selectedVal = selected.val();

                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ActionExecutedContext` class has access to an instance of `HttpContext` so one option you have is to configure an `ActionResult` in your controller that is responsible for setting the value of a session variable that you will access inside of `OnActionExecuted`.